# Google map paid API for static map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to use google map paid api for static map ?

Currently, I am using google static map without any api key and due to restriction on the number of requests on static map api, i want to know how i can use paid api for static map

What are the changes i have to do in my request

Comment: You can include an API Key to your URLs and sign them in order to enable billing.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact sales here:
http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html

Comment: I filled the form, got one mail but the mail have nothing related to static map API, also no information for changes that has to done for using paid map API. I asked this by replying the mail, no reply i received yet.

Comment: does Google also provide trail for this paid API ?

Comment: Do you mean trial? You can ask your sales rep about that.

Comment: but no one is replying my mail from Google, what should i do ?